# Another man in the bed, and I'm ok with it?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

When I came to bed, I found my wife asleep with another man.  I didn't think much of it and joined them.  Later, I was extremely irritated with the threesome and left to find another place to sleep.  In the morning, all was well.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other man is

> your little son. It was OK until he started to cry/move/etc, so you had to move to another room.

Answer (score 2):

The married couple is

> open-minded.

Answer (score 2):

> He is your son.­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

The other man:

> is your wife's aged father who needs looking after at night, you only have the one very large bed and you kept on getting woken up so moved to the quite sofa to get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The other man

> is a pet (dog/cat/whathaveyou) -- my own animals are notorious bedhogs!

Answer (score 0):

The other man is a

> fussy boy, or "little man"

Answer (score 0):

You are a:

> Dog or cat, your "wife" is another dog/cat.

The man is:

> Your master, as well as that of the other pet.

Later, I was extremely irritated with the threesome and left to find another place to sleep.

> If the bed gets too warm, dogs don't like it and might move away to somewhere cooler.

In the morning, all was well.

> Your master fed you. Gave you attention. Played with you. Your life is made!